# Ranking data based on subcategories in R

Tags: r, rank

I have a dataset of 48,000 observations and 9 variables. i am trying to compute the ranking of the variable arl_method1 by the variables nphase1, meanshift, and sigmashift. there are 1000 observations for each combination of nphase1, mean,s-shift. I am trying to have R rank these from 1 to 1000 but i cant see to get the code right, it instead is calculating the rankings based off the entire dataset, so it is producing rankings up to 48k. 
my code:

```
mydata<-read.table("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\R\\study2_total.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
mydata2<-data.frame(mydata, D1=abs(mydata$ARL_method1-desiredrun), D2=abs(mydata$ARL_method2-desiredrun))
mydata2<-mydata2[order(mydata$nphase1, mydata2$meanshift, mydata2$Sigmashift),]
```

i  have tried to do the ranking two different ways both dont seem to produce teh desired output.

```
r1<-data.frame(rank(mydata2$ARL_method1 [order(mydata2$nphase1, mydata2$meanshift, mydata$Sigmashift)])) 
r1<-by(mydata2, mydata2$nphase1 & mydata2$meanshift & mydata$Sigmashift,function(x) rank(mydata2$ARL_method1))
```

this is what i had written previously in SAS, and am trying to convert into R

```
proc rank data=study2 out=rankout;
     var arl_method1 arl_method2;
     by nphase1 meanshift sigmashift;
     ranks ARL_Rank1 ARL_Rank2;
run;
```

any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at ways to use `group_by()` and then `mutate()` in `dplyr` to do this?

Comment: tapply will apply a function based on groups. It might work better for you than by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this in R, depending on what package you like to use.

Your `by` method was almost right, but your second argument should be a list with your columns rather than using `&` to combine them:

```
# using base R and 'by'
# have a look at this output - returns just the rank for each
#  combo of (nphase1, meanshift, Sigmashift)
by(r1, r1[, c('nphase1', 'meanshift', 'Sigmashift')],
   function (x) rank(x$ARL_method1))
```

These options will all add a column `rank` to your dataframe, might be more useful (by virtue of the `mutate(r1, rank=rank(ARL_method1))` for each combination of nphase1/meanshift/sigmashift).

```
# base R using `by`. Same as before but add the ranks to the
#  original dataframe (using `mutate`) and then `rbind` the rows
#  together
do.call(rbind, by(r1, r1[, c('nphase1', 'meanshift', 'Sigmashift')],
        mutate, rank=rank(ARL_method1)))

# plyr package
library(plyr)
ddply(r1, .(nphase1, meanshift, Sigmashift),
      mutate, rank=rank(ARL_method1))

# dplyr package
library(dplyr)
r1 %>%
  group_by(nphase1, meanshift, Sigmashift) %>%
  mutate(rank=rank(ARL_method1))

# data.table package
library(data.table)
setDT(r1)[, rank:=rank(ARL_method1), by="nphase1,meanshift,Sigmashift"]
```

If you're doing this sort of manipulation a lot, I recommend going for a package rather than base R. This sort of operation is very natural in dplyr/plyr/data.table. If efficiency will be an issue, `data.table` is very good at fast joins, data manipulation etc, but has a steeper learning curve.